# SAX Parser PHP no memory at line x

Tags: php, xml, memory, sax, filesize

I m using SAX Parser with php to parse a 1.2GB xml file and the results are written in a txt file. After several minutes I get an error of "no memory at line x". When this is done the text file output is only a few kB (whereas the expected output file could well exceed several MB in size) and has stored very few of the information needed. I m running this project on a windows 7 64bit system with i7 processor and 18 GB RAM, using xampp, but I have also run it at a 32bit system with the same results. I have modified the php.ini with these commands:

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', 72000); 
ini_set('memory_limit','13056M');
ini_set('realpath_cache_size','13056000k');
ini_set('max_input_time','-1');
```

Is there something I should modify in php.ini? Could this be some kind of buffer overflow when the code doesn't find the filtered data to parse and only reads "junk" data? Could this be an error caused by the OS file size restrictions? Has anyone else solved anything similar? 
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you sure that the memory can be reused in your source? If you store the data in variables you will still fill up your memory, even with SAX or XMLReader.

Comment: This is hard to say without seeing your code. Normally SAX Parser (or similar like XMLReader) are known for sequentially handling XML documents (operating on a buffer that's not containing the whole document at once). So it's either some handling in your code *or* there is a memory leak in some of the libraries in use. For the later exact versions and used libs wouldn't hurt either. From what you've posted as code, I don't understand how the realpath cache size should be related to this.

Answer (score 1):

the problem is maybe the function you use to parse the xml file. parsing large xml files with the wrong functions  need a lot of memory because the xml document are "hold back" in your system memory before the results are returned.

i have really good experience with the `XMLReader` class from php to parse large xml files.

http://php.net/manual/en/class.xmlreader.php

don't increase your `memory_limit` to solve this, i think this is the wrong way to fix your error.

for sure you don't show us your whole implementation of your code, the problem can also be found in the way you perform further process collecting your data in php (make a large array, don't `unset` variables) hard to tell.

Answer (score 1):

I have experienced the same problem and my investigation so far points to the version of libxml2 used. Versions higher than 2.7.6 seems to have restrictions on memory usage unless you explicitly allow it to use more than the hardcoded limit (LIBXML_PARSEHUGE).

Check http://php.net/manual/en/libxml.constants.php for details.

Unfortunately I haven't found a solution for the issue which is how to set this option when using the XML Parser functions in PHP. I guess xml_parser_set_option would be the correct place?

Currently it seems like the only option is to update the code to use XMLReader instead. This extension has the option parameter in the open function where you can provide the libxml option constants.

Update!

Looking through the source code of the xml extension I found that the xml_parse function is using the libxml function xmlParseChunk which does not take options. I was able to make it work without providing this option by reducing the chunk size (xml_parse fails with 'No memory' when chunk size is more than 9.5MB). Maybe you can try this:

```
while ($data = fread($fp, 1024*1024)) {
  xml_parse($parser, $data, feof($fp)) or
    die(sprintf('XML ERROR: %s at line %d',
    xml_error_string(xml_get_error_code($parser)),
    xml_get_current_line_number($parser)));
}
```

Comment: From searching around before i stumbled upon the libxml version problem possibility again but i dont know how to downgrade the libxml version or change its parameters.I used these commands to get some basic info from the site u suggested:

print "PHP_VERSION:      ".PHP_VERSION."\n";
print "LIBXML_VERSION:   ".LIBXML_VERSION."\n";
print "huge:      ".LIBXML_PARSEHUGE."\n";

results:
PHP_VERSION: 5.5.11
LIBXML_VERSION: 20901
huge: 524288

I have to admit i cant understand the version of the libxml the way its shown.Same goes for the parsehuge parameter.is it in bytes/kb/mb?

Comment: The xml_parser_set_option doesnt provide such parameter btw.
http://php.net/manual/en/function.xml-parser-set-option.php

I m using xampp as well (latest version)

Answer (score 0):

I have an array but i dont think its growing too large.Its essential i dont clear that array though.No sessions are used either only simple string variables.

I m parsing the dblp.xml file downloaded from the official source so there is little to no chance the xml isnt well formed(contains a valid dtd as well).

I didnt want to post the code cause its kinda large but here it is:

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', 72000);

$professors = array();

$parser = xml_parser_create();

xml_set_element_handler($parser, 'start_element', 'end_element');
xml_set_character_data_handler($parser, 'character_data');

function start_element($parser, $element_name, $element_attrs) {

global $interest;
global $author_id;
global $id;
global $author;
global $no_url;
global $url;
global $professors;
global $counter;
global $author_name;

switch ($element_name) {
    case 'WWW':
        $counter = 0;
        $duplicate = false;
        $author_id = end($element_attrs);

        if (substr($author_id, 0, 9) === 'homepages') {
            for ($i = 0; $i < count($professors); $i++) {
                if ($author_id === $professors[$i]) {
                    $duplicate = true;
                }
            }

            if ($duplicate) {
                $id = false;
                $interest = false;
            }
            else {
                array_push($professors, $author_id);
                $id = true;
                $interest = true;
            }
        }
        break;
    case 'AUTHOR':
        $author_name = "";
        $author = true;
        $no_url = true;
        break;
    case 'URL':
        $url = true;
        $no_url = false;
        break;
}
}

function character_data($parser, $data) {

$fp1 = fopen("Authors.txt","a+");

global $interest;
global $author_id;
global $id;
global $author;
global $no_url;
global $url;
global $counter;
global $author_name;

if ($interest && $id) {
    if ($no_url) {
        fwrite($fp1,"*" . "\r\n");
        fwrite($fp1,$author_id);
    }
    else {
        fwrite($fp1,$author_id);
    }
    $id = false;
}

if ($interest && $author) {

    $author_name .= $data;
}

if ($interest && $url) {

    $url_name = $data;
    fwrite($fp1,"*" . $url_name . "\r\n");
}
}

function end_element($parser, $element_name) {

global $interest;
global $author_id;
global $id;
global $author;
global $url;
global $author_name;

$fp1 = fopen("Authors.txt","a+");   

switch ($element_name) {
    case 'WWW':
        $interest = false;
        break;
    case 'AUTHOR':
        if ($interest && $author) {
            fwrite($fp1,"*" . $author_name);
            $author = false;
        }
        break;
    case 'URL':
        $url = false;
        break;
    case 'DBLP':
        die(sprintf('End of XML'));
        xml_parser_free($parser);
        break;
}
}

$fp = fopen('dblp.xml', 'r')
  or die ("Cannot open dblp.xml!");

while ($data = fread($fp, 100000000)) {  //i give such a huge number to read each time to cover the case of a large line in the xml.i get the same no memory at line error though with the default 4096 value as well
  xml_parse($parser, $data) or
    die(sprintf('XML ERROR: %s at line %d',
    xml_error_string(xml_get_error_code($parser)),
    xml_get_current_line_number($parser)));
}

xml_parser_free($parser);
```